# Devexpress grid lazy loading

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevExpress data grid on an ASP.Net webpage. Because the data that needs to be shown in the grid loads slow I would like the grid to load after the page is fully loaded.

Does DevExpress grid support this?

Comment: Paging is not relevant in this context. The loading can take as long as needed after the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to implement a “postponed” ASPxGridView data binding in the following manner:

1) handle the client-side ASPxClientGridView.Init event that is raised on the client side after the control has been initialized but prior to it being displayed within the browser;

2) perform the ASPxGridView’s custom callback via the client-side ASPxClientGridView.PerformCallback method (pass any data as the parameter);

3) handle the server-side ASPxGridView.CustomCallback event and bind the grid (based on the passed parameter):

```
<dx:ASPxGridView … OnCustomCallback="grid_CustomCallback">
    <ClientSideEvents Init="function(s, e) {
        s.PerformCallback('');
    }" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>

protected void grid_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e) {
    /*e.Parameters*/
    (sender as ASPxGridView).DataBind()
}
```